# Using Metrics with Wildfly 28 and Prometheus and Jakarta EE Application

Tags: prometheus, wildfly, wildfly-28

I'm searching a way to provide simple metrics like the "old way" with http://localhost:9990/metrics but in Wildfly 29.

With Wildfly 28 they removed the `MicroProfile Metrics` support and added `micrometer` and `MicroProfile Telemetry`. But both of the new subsystems seems to work as a push-principle.

I do not have a `opentelemetry-collector` in my stack and would like to keep it that way.

So my question:

> Is there any way to create custom metrics with Wildfly 28 and prometheus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not currently possible to do that. If the feature is super important to you, please file an RFE on the WildFly tracker at https://issues.redhat.com. We don't have *concrete* plans on how to evolve that subsystem, so having requests like this is important for planning our work. If you're super-ambitious, pull requests are always welcome, and if you choose to go this route, come find me on the WildFly Zulip (https://wildfly.zulipchat.com) and I'd be happy to help you however you need through the process.